# Vidalia gives this error. How to make it connect?

Tags: 14.04, vpn, tor, vidalia

```
Aug 31 17:09:32.025 [Warning] Tried connecting to router at 193.23.244.244:443, but identity key was not as expected: wanted 7BE683E65D48141321C5ED92F075C55364AC7123 but got B0E8B26991725D15AD3F3F8F48FE8462E00A9805.
```

Comment: Just as a note, you can hope to get better help at http://tor.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This sounds like someone is messing with your connection. Are you behind some proxy or need to sign in somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Vidalia has been discontinued for long because it was not keeping up with changes in Tor, and has been replaced with Tor Launcher, which is a Firefox extension that provides similar functionality.

From TBB [release-note](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/tor-browser-bundle-35-released):

> In terms of user-facing changes from TBB 2.x, the 3.x series primarily
>   features the replacement of Vidalia with a Firefox-based Tor
>   controller called Tor Launcher. This has resulted in a vast decrease
>   in startup times, and a vast increase in usability.

It is discontinued for a reason and it is not recommend to use. If you still want to try hooking Vidalia upto TBB 3.5, follow the guidelines in the [FAQ](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorBrowserBundle3FAQ#WheredidtheworldmapVidaliago) section.